# Why does my CreateThread input parameter get corrupted?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, windows-shell

In a namespace extension, I'm creating a thread and passing in a file path to the thread function. 
The problem I'm seeing is the first character of the file path gets corrupted. D:\temp0.csv gets passed in and in the thread function it becomes Y:\temp0.csv or some other random corrupted first wchar. In Win2k8R2 and Win10 it was working fine, but sometimes it would fail in the same way. I tried disabling optimizations to no avail.
The fileName variable is populated from the IShellItem that came from the IFileOpenDialog. 
What do I need to do to fix this?

Caller of thread function:

```
LPWSTR filePath       = NULL;
IFileOpenDialog *ofd  = NULL;
IShellItem *file      = NULL;
hrPath                = file->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &filePath);
CreateThread(NULL, 0, CCsv::BuildTree, static_cast<LPVOID>(filePath), 0, NULL);
```

static class thread function

```
DWORD WINAPI CCsv::BuildTree(LPVOID lpParam) {
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    LPWSTR filePath = static_cast<LPWSTR>(lpParam);
}
```

Here is a minimal program, but it does not repro with this code. One  difference is I added a wait for the thread function. THat doesn't exist in the namespace extension.

main.cpp

```
// buf.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"


using std::wstring;
static CRITICAL_SECTION g_TreeLock;
static CRITICAL_SECTION g_MountQueueLock;


class CCsv 
{
public:
    CCsv();
    ~CCsv();
    static DWORD WINAPI BuildTree(LPVOID lpParam);
};
class CMountPath {
public:
    CMountPath();
    ~CMountPath();
    BOOL Mount();
    BOOL PathExists(LPWSTR path);
private:
    CSimpleArray<wstring>   m_MountQueue;
};
extern CCsv g_Csv;

CCsv::CCsv() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&g_TreeLock);
}

CCsv::~CCsv() {
    DeleteCriticalSection(&g_TreeLock);
}
DWORD WINAPI CCsv::BuildTree(LPVOID lpParam) {
    LPWSTR name = static_cast<LPWSTR>(lpParam);
    MessageBox(NULL, name, L"", MB_OK);
    CoTaskMemFree(name);
    return 0;
}

CMountPath::CMountPath() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&g_MountQueueLock);
}

CMountPath::~CMountPath() {
 DeleteCriticalSection(&g_MountQueueLock);
}
BOOL CMountPath::PathExists(LPWSTR path) {
    return FALSE;
}
BOOL CMountPath::Mount() {
    IEnumIDList *idl                    = NULL;
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl                   = NULL;
    LPITEMIDLIST desktopPidl            = NULL;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlRelative          = NULL;
    BOOL success                        = FALSE;
    HRESULT hr, hrPath                  = S_FALSE;
    LPWSTR filePath                     = NULL;
    PWSTR filePathHeap                  = NULL;
    WCHAR msg[MAXPATH+MAXMSG]           = {0};
    IFileOpenDialog *ofd                = NULL;
    IShellItem *file                    = NULL;
    DWORD idx                           = 0;
    BOOL isQueued                       = FALSE;

    const COMDLG_FILTERSPEC fileSpec[]  = { 
            { L"CSV Text Files", L"*.csv" },
            { L"All Files", L"*.*" },
    };
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ofd));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            ofd->SetTitle(L"Choose file");
            ofd->SetFileTypes(ARRAYSIZE(fileSpec), fileSpec);
            hr = ofd->Show(NULL);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
                hr = ofd->GetResult(&file);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
                hrPath = file->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &filePath);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hrPath)){
                LPWSTR filePathHeap = (LPWSTR)CoTaskMemAlloc(MAXPATH * sizeof(WCHAR));
                if(filePathHeap) {
                    StringCchCopy(filePathHeap, MAXPATH, filePath);
                    if(PathExists(filePathHeap)) {
                        StringCchPrintf(msg, MAXPATH+MAXMSG, L"The file %s is already loaded.", filePathHeap);
                        MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"appname", MB_OK);
                    }
                    else {
                        EnterCriticalSection(&g_MountQueueLock);
                        isQueued = !m_MountQueue.Find(wstring(filePathHeap)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                        if(!isQueued)
                            m_MountQueue.Add(wstring(filePathHeap));
                        LeaveCriticalSection(&g_MountQueueLock);
                        if(!isQueued) {
                            HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CCsv::BuildTree, static_cast<LPVOID>(filePathHeap), 0, NULL);
                            // there is no wait in the namespace extension. the wait is just to keep the console app main thread running.
                            if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hThread)
                                WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
                        }
                        else {
                            StringCchPrintf(msg, MAXPATH+MAXMSG, L"The file %s is already being loaded.", filePathHeap);
                            MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"appname", MB_OK);
                        }
                    }
                }
                CoTaskMemFree(filePath);
                file->Release();
            }
        }
        ofd->Release();
    }

    return success;
}

int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CMountPath m;
    m.Mount();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once
#define MAXPATH 32767 
#define MAXMSG 128
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WINVER 0x0600 
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <atlcoll.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <Shobjidl.h>
#include <ShlGuid.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string>
```

Comment: It smells like a classic race condition. You pass a pointer to storage that gets overwritten before `BuildTree` has a chance to read it.

Comment: no - here no race condition - after `file->GetDisplayName` return `filePath` we owner of this memory. and need free it with `CoTaskMemFree` when it no more needed. this look like as heap corrupt. faster of all buffer overrun

Comment: It happens all the time on an 8 proc machine, but my dev box (slower 2 core) doesn't have this problem. The 8 proc system has 56GB RAM and the devbox only has 16GB. After file->GetDisplayName, I copied the string to the heap then released IShellItem and freed filePath in the caller. That leaves a new string on the heap for the thread function to use, yet still the first wchar is being corrupted before it gets casted. Any ideas on how to fix or work around this? .

Comment: @505HPC6Z06 - but this not explain where/why error. need more scr code from you or catch/reproduce this error in small separate example. for what you copied the string to the heap ? you can direct pass filePath to thread

Comment: I copied the path to the heap because later in the function after CreateThread() is called, the path was being freed. I thought maybe there would be a race condition where the first char was being freed in the caller while the thread function tried to read it. But that would probably be a crash. Grabbing at straws here.

Comment: @505HPC6Z06 - need of course only code which direct manipulate with filePath - alloc/free/copy. and you try say that after you copy string to heap, just before pass to working thread it correct, but in working thread already wrong ?

Comment: @505HPC6Z06 - in this case look like you free exactly string in first thread, which you pass to second thread. but hard say without src code

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: added example program, but the buffer problem doesn't repro with it. However, it gives a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: After adding a 4 second wait in the namespace extension after calling CreateThread, the buffer does not get corrupted and works as expected. I don't want to wait though as thats programming by chance. I don't know why the wait is working around the problem plus that wait stalls the Explorer UI.

Comment: @505HPC6Z06 - Assuming you're using Visual Studio, can't you put a hardware data breakpoint on the first character of the buffer to see what is writing over that character?

Comment: @RbMm, yes the buffer gets corrupted after calling CreateThread() and before entering the BuildTree() thread procedure . Looking at the memory pointed to by lpParam stopped at a bp on BuildTree() function entry, the first wchar is corrupted.

Comment: There's no point in posting code that doesn't exhibit the problem you're talking about!  You need to figure out the difference between your working code and your failing code.  Typically you would do that by pulling out sections of the failing code until it starts working, then carefully examining the last section you removed.

Comment: harry, I already explained the difference and yes there is a point in posting the code regardless. @rcgldr, thats a good suggestion to see who is writing out of bounds and onto my memory.

Comment: You mentioned *one* difference, so presumably there are others.  Or are you saying that the posted code exhibits the problem if you remove the WaitForSingleObject call?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using threads at all?  When you spawn a new thread, you are blocking your code waiting for the thread to terminate before continuing, so you are serializing all of your code.  You may as well not even use threads at all.

Also, you have memory leaks and various logic errors in your code.

Try this instead:

```
// buf.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

using std::wstring;

class CCsv 
{
public:
    CCsv();
    ~CCsv();

    void BuildTree(LPCWSTR name);

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_TreeLock;
};

class CMountPath {
public:
    CMountPath();
    ~CMountPath();

    BOOL Mount();
    BOOL PathExists(LPCWSTR path);

private:
    CSimpleArray<wstring> m_MountQueue;
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_MountQueueLock;
};

CCsv g_Csv;

CCsv::CCsv() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_TreeLock);
}

CCsv::~CCsv() {
    DeleteCriticalSection(&m_TreeLock);
}

void CCsv::BuildTree(LPCWSTR name) {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, name, L"", MB_OK);
}

CMountPath::CMountPath() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_MountQueueLock);
}

CMountPath::~CMountPath() {
    DeleteCriticalSection(&m_MountQueueLock);
}

BOOL CMountPath::PathExists(LPCWSTR path) {
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL CMountPath::Mount() {
    BOOL success                        = FALSE;
    HRESULT hr                          = S_FALSE;
    LPWSTR filePath                     = NULL;
    WCHAR msg[MAXPATH+MAXMSG]           = {0};
    IFileOpenDialog *ofd                = NULL;
    IShellItem *file                    = NULL;
    BOOL isQueued                       = FALSE;

    const COMDLG_FILTERSPEC fileSpec[]  = { 
            { L"CSV Text Files", L"*.csv" },
            { L"All Files", L"*.*" },
    };

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ofd));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        ofd->SetTitle(L"Choose file");
        ofd->SetFileTypes(ARRAYSIZE(fileSpec), fileSpec);
        hr = ofd->Show(NULL);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
            hr = ofd->GetResult(&file);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = file->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &filePath);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                if(PathExists(filePath)) {
                    StringCchPrintf(msg, ARRAYSIZE(msg), L"The file %s is already loaded.", filePath);
                    MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"appname", MB_OK);
                }
                else {
                    EnterCriticalSection(&m_MountQueueLock);
                    isQueued = !m_MountQueue.Find(filePath) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                    if(!isQueued)
                        m_MountQueue.Add(filePath);
                    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_MountQueueLock);
                    if(!isQueued) {
                        CCsv::BuildTree(filePath);
                    }
                    else {
                        StringCchPrintf(msg, ARRAYSIZE(msg), L"The file %s is already being loaded.", filePath);
                        MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"appname", MB_OK);
                    }
                }
                CoTaskMemFree(filePath);
            }
            file->Release();
        }
        ofd->Release();
    }

    return success;
}

int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CMountPath m;
    m.Mount();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why am I using a thread? Because I'm not going to do work on a UI thread.

Comment: The code you showed is blocking the main thread while waiting for the worker thread to do its work. And it has to wait, since memory ends up getting freed after `Mount()` exits, causing race conditions and such if the thread is still running. So there is no benefit to using a worker thread at all in your example. If what you showed is not what your NSE is really doing, then you need to post your real NSE code, not different code.

Answer (score 0):

your conceptual mistake here:

```
if(!isQueued) 
{
  m_MountQueue.Add(wstring(filePathHeap));
  CreateThread(NULL, 0, CCsv::BuildTree, static_cast<LPVOID>(filePathHeap), 0, NULL);
}
```

so you insert `filePathHeap` in some database and simultaneously pass this `filePathHeap` to some thread. question - who is OWNER of `filePathHeap` ? who must free it ? if you free it from `BuildTree` - in `m_MountQueue` will be invalid pointer ? you not show code who and how handle `m_MountQueue` - may be this code pop and free `filePathHeap` before it used in `BuildTree`.

in general - if you push `filePathHeap` to `m_MountQueue` - you must not direct use it pointer after this, but have working thread (*pool*) which pop data from `m_MountQueue` , process and free it. or if you direct use `filePathHeap` you must not insert it to `m_MountQueue`.

in case if you need simultaneously working with `filePathHeap` from several threads - you need ref count have. some like this:

```
class CFilePath 
{
    PWSTR _filePath;
    LONG _dwRef;

    ~CFilePath()
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(_filePath);
    }

public:

    PCWSTR getPath() { return _filePath; }

    CFilePath(PWSTR filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
        _dwRef = 1;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }
};

ULONG CALLBACK CCsv::BuildTree(CFilePath* p)
{
    MessageBoxW(0, p->getPath(), L"use path in thread 2", MB_OK);
    p->Release();
    return 0;
}

BOOL CMountPath::Mount() {

...
    if (CFilePath* p = new CFilePath(filePath))
    {
        p->AddRef();

        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, reinterpret_cast<PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(CCsv::BuildTree), p, 0, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else
        {
            p->Release();
        }

        MessageBoxW(0, p->getPath(), L"use path in thread 1", MB_OK);
        p->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(filePath);
    }
...
}
```

Secondly - this code

```
LPWSTR filePathHeap = (LPWSTR)CoTaskMemAlloc(MAXPATH * sizeof(WCHAR));
if(filePathHeap) StringCchCopy(filePathHeap, MAXPATH, filePath);
```

absolutely unnecessary. you can direct use `filePath` as is, but not reallocate it. for what ?!

thirdly - as in previous answer - almost no sense create thread and after this just wait on it exit.

```
                    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CCsv::BuildTree, static_cast<LPVOID>(filePathHeap), 0, NULL);
                    // there is no wait in the namespace extension. the wait is just to keep the console app main thread running.
                    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hThread)
                        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
```

why in this case not direct call `CCsv::BuildTree(filePathHeap);` with same effect ?

also can note that `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` returned only for `CreateFile` or `Socket` - so for file handles only. all another object creating api (including `CreateThread` return 0 on error, but not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (-1) ) - so you incorrect check error condition. 
and finally who will call `CloseHandle(hThread)` ? handle not auto closed when thread exit

Comment: m_MountQueue.Add() accepts a wstring, I see no issue with it. The INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE is a good catch. There is a lot more to pick at in the code I posted. Its quick and dirty. The CoTaskMemAlloc() was to ensure the buffer sent to CreateThread() was not being corrupted/freed by me. It is not production code. I'm looking to know why I'm getting buffer corruption. If you have some ideas about it, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @505HPC6Z06 `m_MountQueue.Add(wstring(filePathHeap));` and `CreateThread(NULL, 0, CCsv::BuildTree, static_cast<LPVOID>(filePathHeap), 0, NULL);` - this is main. for what you insert `filePathHeap` to `m_MountQueue.`? how you use this ? who free the `filePathHeap` ?

Comment: @RbMm: `m_MountQueue` holds `std::wstring` values. Passing `filePathHeap` to `Add()` is making a *copy* of the character data. `filePathHeap` itself needs to be freed afterwards. That is being done in the thread procedure when it calls `CoTaskMemFree(name)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - understand. i not know about **copy** of `filePathHeap` and thinked that direct pointers saved. if *copy* - this of course all changed and my assumption wrong